# Como pegar o caminho absoluto do blade a partir da View?

Tags: laravel

Laravel 4.2

Preciso pegar o diretório do .blade completo depois de sua renderização, como fazer isso?

Tenho tentado navegar através do Application, isso parecer ser uma péssima ideia, entretanto não encontrei nenhum método nativo que faça isso.

```
dump(app()->__get('view')->getFinder());
```

Comment: "_Tenho tentado navegar através do Application, isso parecer ser uma péssima ideia_", mas precisar do caminho das _views_ também não é nenhuma maravilha de ideia, não acha?

Comment: Concordo, eu preciso na verdade apenas para facilitar o desenvolvimento aqui, criando um link para abrir a view no vscode a partir do browser, entendeu?

Comment: Saquei, faz sentido então. Mas por que você acha que seria ruim usar o método que foi citado na sua pergunta?

Comment: De uma olhada nos `helpers`[1](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/helpers) do laravel, pode ser que ache algo que ajude.

Comment: @LINQ, ainda não consegui acessar a class View por este caminho, mas estou trabalhando nisso. Achei uma má prática por que considerei que isso já fosse mais comum de ser feito, logo deveria ter um método próprio. Mas como você falou que esse acesso já é meio estranho, provavel que não exista mesmo.

Comment: @MarceloBoni, isso geralmente é a primeira coisa que faço rsrs

Comment: Resolvido amigos, obrigado pela atenção!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crie um Filtro para que o nome da View se torne disponível nela própria.

`filters.php`

```
/**
 * Compartilha a globalmente variavel $view_name com o nome da view corrente
 */
View::composer('*', function ($view) {
    View::share('view_name', $view->getName());
});
```

A partir disso, pode usar `$view_name` em qualquer View.